# What is the best practice to do this?

Tags: vector, images

I am a GIS Specialist and I have a few images that I want to use them for my software, ESRI ArcGIS, however, each of them has pixels and when you convert them to vector and it does not smooth the pixel. I know this is not a easy way to do it but do you have any suggest for me to work on it ? I want them to save them as a symbol and use them to create it as an icon on the map.

[image]
[image]
[image][image]

and just several more I have...

Does that mean when I have to do manually myself with a program such as Inkscape, Photoshop, Illustrator ?

Comment: Those look basic enough that you can use Illustrator's `Image trace`

Comment: Redrawing those four takes about 4 minutes in Inkscape or illustrator.  A pro level user needs maybe only 2 minutes. No complex techniques nor cryptic commands are needed.

Comment: any suggest when you redraw, which sized should I save as ?

Comment: So is Inkscape is like to Adobe Illustrator's ? I used to have Photoshop on my personal computer; however, my current work does not have any . I don't know if they will allow me to have inksacpe. What about the portable that doesn't required me to install it ?

Comment: Draw into any size in Inkscape or Illustrator, they can be scaled infinitely. In practice really draw to few centimeters size to be able easily to print some onto paper in big size or easily to export as PNGs or other raster photo formats that do not need to be made bigger, only to smaller.

Answer (score 3):

These are simple enough that if you are generally even slightly familiar with Inkscape or Illustrator you can just **redraw** them quickly (and get *much* better results than any tracing feature).

I would *not* use Photoshop if the goal is to eliminate the raster (pixelated) edges.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, image trace is definitely what you would need to do. However, it might be too pixelated to work. What you could do is, open the image in Photoshop and then create a new document. In the new document you're going to want to set it to inches and change the resolution (I set it to 300 and the inches to 8x10). Click create, then copy and paste the image into the new document. Go to edit, free transform, and make the image fit the page. Click apply, make sure the image is black-and-white and then save it as a JPEG. Open it up in illustrator and then do your image trace. Even though the image is blurry there should be enough pixels for the image trace to get the overall shape.